# Qt не может найти GStreamer

Tags: qt, opensuse

Пытаюсь скомпилировать проект с помощью Qt в котором вложен `GStreamer`. Но при компилировании, тут же показывает ошибку `#include <gst/video/gstvideometa.h> no such file or directory.` Проверил файлы, все на месте. Установлен только `gstreamer-1.0`. ОСь- `Opensuse 42.3`. Скачан и установлен был `GStreamer` через `YaST` - стандартный `GUI` установщик на `Opensuse`. Нужно ли прописывать что-то в `.pro`?

Comment: А каталог для поиска инклюдов вы указали?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов действительно забыл...